# Pass object data to styles in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to be able to pass data from a object to the `<styles>` in a single file component. However, it doesn't seem like this is possible.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```html
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return { color: "#f00" }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
    background-color: this.color
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you are not able to pass data from the component to its stylesheets.

The best practice as far as dynamic styling is to use `v-bind:class` or `v-bind:style` if needed. The `<style>` section should be used for the CSS templating language only.

```vue
<template>
    <p :style="{ backgroundColor: bgColor }">Lorem ipsum</p>
</template>
    
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                bgColor: '#000'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions!

**Update**

Since the goal is to use it for Sass functions like darken, I would recommend managing the various colors needed through utility classes instead.

Comment: I know, but I want it to be able to pass the object data to a SCSS file as we are in need of controlling colors - Example like darken(color, 10%) - But that's not possible if you pass the data object to an element in the html

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and your example is incorrect

Comment: @thanksd Thanks for flagging the problem! I used the event binding syntax  out of habit instead of the standard v-bind syntax.