# Vue - Binding data in css with braces syntax

Tags: css, vue.js

How can I bind my Vue component data in the style tag as such? This approach seems the most intuitive but it doesn't work.

```
<template lang="pug">
    div {{album.name}}
</template>

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url({{album.images[0].url}});
    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {...}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is impossible as far as I know, a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983037/pass-object-data-to-styles-in-vue-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put vue bind in styles.

if you want to  tag's background-image, try in vue component like this

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted: function () {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${this.album.images[0].url}")`;
    },
    data() {
        return {...}
    }
}
</script>
```

or if you want change background when album.images changed, just put code on **watch** property

Comment: Can I use `watch` to remove the background image when navigating away from the page?

Comment: I suggest use **beforeDestroy** or **destroyed** property.