# Use the same variable both in scss and vue?

Tags: vue.js, sass

Use the same variable both in scss and vue?

[image: screenshot here]

I need to calculate the number from data, and they need to be the same value. How can I use the same variable from vue in sass file?

And some calculations are made using this value.

View the source file at codepen `(https://codepen.io/EricBugfree/pen/mXEpey)`.

Comment: are you using a build system for your project? webpack? browserify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass object data to styles in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983037/pass-object-data-to-styles-in-vue-js)

Comment: I use webpack and you can view the online version here.
https://codepen.io/EricBugfree/pen/mXEpey

Comment: Have you considered using native CSS variables?

Comment: Like here https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/NydgWz

Answer (score 0):

You really can't have the 2 communicate because sass compiles down to simple css and removes all it variables. However there are 2 options I can think of that works. First you can define the sass variable as a `:root` CSS variable

```
:root{ --circleQuantity:#{$circleQuantity}}
```

Then access that variable using javascript to set the variable in vue using something like this:

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root')

function getStyle(name){
    let select = getComputedStyle(root)
    return select.getPropertyValue(name)
}
```

This will allow you to set that variables you want only in your sass environment, but it also leaves remnants of itself and you may run into issues with loading order as well as other issues like the need to remove unit values (like px) from them in order to be used appropriately.

Another way to approach this issue is to define your variables in an outside file like in a var.json/env.json file then import that file into both your .vue file and also in your sass file. While this is pretty trivial in a javascript framework like vue, sass does not natively support this functionality. However, there is something called "node-sass-json-importer" which I have used that can do this.

Use your package manager (npm/yarn/etc) to install this (or add it to your package.json file) then include the importer in your particular webpack .config file. For reference here is my vite.config file in a project using this exact method:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import jsonImporter from "node-sass-json-importer"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        importer: jsonImporter(),
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  server:{
    host: false,
    port: 8000,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
})
```